# No SQL Server como converter string parte maiúscula parte minúscula baseado no separador: \?

Tags: sql-server, string

Preciso fazer um script para converter todos os registros de usuário em uma tabela nesse formato (campo único):

```
INFORMATICA\desenvolvedor  
ADMINISTRACAO\contador
```

Ou seja, antes da barra em maiúsculo e depois da barra em minusculo. Como fazer isso no SQL Server?

Atualmente os registros estão assim (campo único):

```
informatica\desenvolvedor ou  
INFORMATICA\DESENVOLVEDOR
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não sei se é a solução mais elegante, mas atende seu caso:

```sql
select Upper(Substring(t.texto, 0, CHARINDEX ( '\' ,t.texto) ) ) 
       + '\' + 
       lower(Substring(t.texto, CHARINDEX ( '\' ,t.texto) + 1, LEN(t.texto)) )
from (
    select 'administrador\edgar' as texto
) as t
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, baseado na sua resposta criei uma função que basta passar a string como parametro. Postarei abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma função criada a partir da resposta do Edgar, para somente passar a string como parâmetro.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION FORMATAR_USUARIO(@STRING VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(SUBSTRING(@STRING, 0, CHARINDEX ( '\' ,@STRING) ) ) + '\' +    LOWER(SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX ( '\' ,@STRING) + 1, LEN(@STRING)) )
END
```

Sendo assim, depois de criada a função, para utilizar basta:

```sql
SELECT dbo.FORMATAR_USUARIO('uuuuu\oooooo')
```

Output:

```
UUUUU\oooooo
```